# How to add images to product gallery programmatically in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, media

How to add images to product gallery programmatically in magento2...

Answer (score 12):

Use Below code to add images,thumbnail

Use following code to add/remove image from product in Magento2.

```
// Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

// Remove Images From Product
$productId = ; // Id of product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);

// Add Images To The Product
$imagePath = "sample.png"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Reference Url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259303/add-remove-image-programmatically-to-product-magento2

Comment: Note that this code creates product attributes 'image', 'small_image', and 'thumbnail', and does so on the specified store view level. For example: add $product->setStoreId(0) if you want the attributes to work globally.

Comment: I have tried your solution, But it is not removing the existing images..

Answer (score 0):

for me this solution not working.

I find another solution, working for me but also with bugs.

If my image is not big all is good, but if image is big (2.69MB 4000x2860px) I not have any errors, I not have "return 'XXXXX'" but product is saved and in frontend I have product with image

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($copiedProduct->getID());
$mediaGalleryProcessor = $om->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor');
$mediaGalleryProcessor->addImage($product,$path,array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
$product->save(); return 'XXXXXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
  if(sizeof($imgs) > 1) {
            /* Assign additional images to existing products */
            $product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($newProdId);
            $productRepository = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
            $productRepository->save($product);

            for ( $i=1; $i<sizeof($imgs); $i++ ) {

                echo 'Add Images :' . $prdbasepath.basename(trim($imgs[$i])) . PHP_EOL;
                $image_directory = $prdbasepath.'data'.DS.basename(trim($imgs[$i]));

                if (file_exists($image_directory) && getimagesize($image_directory)) {

                    echo 'File exists'.PHP_EOL;
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                    $product->save();

                }
            }

        }
```

Please refer the below tutorial for initializing object manager and set the file path.

https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/programmatically-add-multiple-images-magento-2/